# FreeIPA сообщает, что DNS зоны нет... И что она есть

Tags: linux, dns, freeipa

Я, похоже, упускаю из виду какую-то мелочь, но знание сего факта не помогает мне понять что происходит.
А происходит следующее: FreeIPA не показывает зону DNS, но и не даёт её добавить сообщая что такая зона уже существует.

```sh
user@ipa:~$ ipa dnszone-find
----------------------------
Number of entries returned 0
----------------------------
user@ipa:~$ ipa dnszone-show domain.local
ipa: ERROR: domain.local.: DNS zone not found
user@ipa:~$ ipa dnszone-enable domain.local
ipa: ERROR: domain.local.: DNS zone not found
user@ipa:~$ ipa dnszone-disable domain.local
ipa: ERROR: domain.local.: DNS zone not found
user@ipa:~$ ipa dnszone-add domain.local
ipa: ERROR: DNS zone domain.local. already exists in DNS and is handled by server(s): ipa.domain.local.
user@ipa:~$ klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:1000
Default principal: admin@DOMAIN.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
10/21/2021 13:26:51  10/22/2021 13:26:43  HTTP/ipa.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL
10/21/2021 13:26:48  10/22/2021 13:26:43  krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL
user@ipa:~$
```